how to set the following environment variables: PRIVATE_KEY, Source Blockchain RPC URL, Destination Blockchain RPC URL
https://github.com/smartcontractkit/ccip-starter-kit-hardhat?tab=readme-ov-file
I want test this project,at usage 2.
I do not know how to set the following environment variables: PRIVATE_KEY, Source Blockchain RPC URL, Destination Blockchain RPC URL.
the error as fallow:
An unexpected error occurred:
Error: private key not provided - check your environment variables

By following the usage section, you’ve to perform the following steps:

Install the @chainlink/env-enc dependency using this command:
npm install @chainlink/env-enc


Set a password for encrypting and decrypting the environment variable file, using this command:
npx env-enc set-pw


Set the environment variables (as given in the .env.example file) along with the PRIVATE_KEY, and assign them their respective values, by following the instructions in the terminal, using this command:
npx env-enc set


After executing the above command, the .env.enc file will be automatically generated. And, you’ll be good to go with executing the code.


P.S. You can get the blockchain RPC url by getting the API key from RPC providers like Alchemy or Infura. And, you can get the PRIVATE_KEY by exporting it from your MetaMask.
If you don’t find your desired chain/network on Alchemy or Infura, then you can also opt for getting some public RPC url from Chainlist.

Thank you very much. I have solved this problem with your help
